# Having issues with nested While Loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i'm using nested while loops to try and iterate through these functions, and i don't see why on the 2nd and etc. loops through the 2nd loop why it keeps printing out the same numbers it should be larger every subsequent loop.

I honestly don't know what exactly i messed up, it's most likely something small if anyone can point to what the issue i'd very much appreciate it.

```
import math

p = 1
n = 10

while n < 321:
    p = 1

    while p < 129:
        T_serial = n ^ 2
        T_parallel = (T_serial / p) + math.log(p)
        speed = T_serial / T_parallel
        effic = speed / p
        result = speed / effic
        print(result)
        p *= 2

    n += 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shows you what is going on:

```
import math

p = 1.0
n = 10.0

print "n\tp\tresult"

while n < 321.0:
    p = 1

    while p < 129.0:
        #print "n", n, "p", p
        T_serial = n**2.0
        T_parallel = (T_serial / p) + math.log(p)
        speed = T_serial / T_parallel
        effic = speed / p
        result = speed / effic
        print "%s\t%s\t%s" % (n, p, result)
        p *= 2.0
    n += 10.0
```

Output:

```
n       p       result
10.0    1       1.0
10.0    2.0     2.0
10.0    4.0     4.0
10.0    8.0     8.0
10.0    16.0    16.0
10.0    32.0    32.0
10.0    64.0    64.0
10.0    128.0   128.0
20.0    1       1.0
20.0    2.0     2.0
20.0    4.0     4.0
20.0    8.0     8.0
20.0    16.0    16.0
20.0    32.0    32.0
20.0    64.0    64.0
20.0    128.0   128.0
30.0    1       1.0
30.0    2.0     2.0
30.0    4.0     4.0
30.0    8.0     8.0
30.0    16.0    16.0
30.0    32.0    32.0
30.0    64.0    64.0
30.0    128.0   128.0
40.0    1       1.0
[etc...]
```

Look at your equations for `effic` and `result`. In the end you just did

```
results = speed / effic = speed / (speed / p) = p
```

So no wonder it is not what you expected. You are simply printing `p` each time.

Comment: im expecting the 2nd lop through while p < 129 to have n = 20 instead of 10 as it is on the first way around. also the indenation was just my mistake adding it to stack overflow. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

there's an indentation error in your first while loop.

```
import math

p = 1
n = 10

while n < 321:

    p = 1

    while p < 129:
        T_serial = n ^ 2
        T_parallel = (T_serial / p) + math.log(p)
        speed = T_serial / T_parallel
        effic = speed / p
        result = speed / effic
        print(result)
        p *= 2

    n += 10
```

Comment: Sorry that was due to me incorrectly putting into stackoverflow i'll edit accordingly.